# Arduino Esp8266 module stuck during upload

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I'm have been trying too upload a code  via Arduino Mega too ESP8266 esp-01

It gives the following message
.
.
.

> Leaving....
>
> hard resetting via rst pin

And it get stuck there

I have researched and  no success

Comment: this is normal end of the upload. do you have io 0 pulled down all time? pull it up to start the application. with io 0 LOW if always returns to flashing mode

Comment: What's an io (is it input and output)

Comment: it is like gpio without gp. gpio is general purpose input output, io is not general purpose. esp01 has 4 io pins of esp8266 on the header. RX, TX, 0 and 2

Comment: https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap01%20-%20ESP8266.html

Comment: Thanks I got it now works